# Pandas filter df by values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
ID Component Avg
218 23a      1.88
218 12b      1.88
218 1e       4
530 2b       2.67
530 2d       2.55
231 1e       1
231 2d       1.67
689 1e       2.55
689 2b       4
689 3a       3
619 23b      1.67
619 12b      2
```

I need to get a list of `ID`'s that have no Avg under 2.51 for any `Component`.

I've tried using `.loc` and other basic filtering, but I'm not sure how to iterate through all the `Component` values for each `ID`.

My desired output would look like this

```
ID
530
689
```

Comment: Do you mean *over* 2.51?

Comment: @sundance - sorry, fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude out of scope IDs:

```
exc = df.loc[df['Avg'] < 2.51, 'ID'].unique()
res = df['ID'][~df['ID'].isin(exc)].unique()

print(res)

array([530, 689], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the max `Avg` for each ID using `groupby`, and then filter that:

```
maxes = df.groupby("ID")["Avg"].max()
result = maxes[maxes["Avg"] < 2.51].index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Make df
data = {'ID': [218, 218, 218, 530, 530, 231, 231, 689, 689, 689, 619, 619],
        'Component': ['23a', '12b', '1e', '2b', '2d', '1e', '2d', '1e', '2b', '3a', '23b', '12b'],
        'Avg': [1.88, 1.88, 4, 2.67, 2.55, 1, 1.67, 2, 4, 3, 1.67, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#Get lowest Average
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,index='Component',values='Avg',aggfunc=min)

pivot=pivot.reset_index()

#Identify averages less than 2.51
pivot['Test'] = np.where(pivot['Avg']<2.51,1,0)

pivot=pivot.drop('Avg',axis=1)

df2=pd.merge(df,pivot,on='Component')

# Filter to passing components
df2[df2['Test']==0]
```